# Django-Haystack-Elastisearch "text" field is empty

Tags: django, django-haystack

After running an index_update command I get the following message:

Indexing 452 quorum_ sensings
  indexed 1 - 452 of 452 (by 4672)

This is good as there are 452 rows of data in the database. However, when I check the data fields all the data fields contain data except for the "text" field. Hence, I cannot search the database using Haystack.

What would cause the "text' field to be empty? Would, textfields in the database cause this? Any help would be much appreciated!

Here is some of my code:

search-indexes.py

```
from bacterial.models import Quorum_Sensing
from haystack import indexes

class Quorum_SensingIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True, template_name='quorum_sensing_text.txt')
    Category_Inducer_Molecule = indexes.CharField(model_attr='Category_Inducer_Molecule', faceted=True)
    Inducer_Name_Synonym_Abbreviation = indexes.CharField(model_attr='Inducer_Name_Synonym_Abbreviation', faceted=True)
    Amino_Acid_Sequence_Inducer = indexes.CharField(model_attr='Amino_Acid_Sequence_Inducer', faceted=True)
    Organism_Involved = indexes.CharField(model_attr='Organism_Involved', faceted=True)
    Target_Protein = indexes.CharField(model_attr='Target_Protein', faceted=True)
    Broad_Functional_Category_Target_Molecule = indexes.CharField(model_attr='Broad_Functional_Category_Target_Molecule',faceted=True)

    def get_model(self):
        return Quorum_Sensing

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

models.py

```
class Quorum_Sensing(models.Model):
    IUAPAC_NAME = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    Inducer_Molecule = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Category_Inducer_Molecule = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    Inducer_Name_Synonym_Abbreviation = models.TextField()
    Chemical_Nature_Inducer_Molecule = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    Natural_Synthetic = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    Pubchem_Link_Inducer_Molecules = models.URLField()
    Mass_Inducer_Molecule = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Number_Amino_Acids_In_Inducer_Molecule = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    IUPAC_Chemical_ID = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    QuorumPep_Link = models.URLField()
    Amino_Acid_Sequence_Inducer = models.CharField (max_length=300)
    SMILES = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    Organism_Involved = models.CharField (max_length=200)
    Strain1 = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    Strain2 = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    Strain3 = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    Strain4 = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    Strain5 = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    Taxonomy_Link = models.URLField()
    Pathogenic_Or_Not = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    Host = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    Target_Protein = models.CharField (max_length=160)
    Target_Protein_Length = models.CharField (max_length=40)
    Gene_Name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    Broad_Functional_Category_Target_Molecule = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    GI = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    NCBI_Link_Target_Molecule = models.URLField(max_length=400)
    Mode_Of_Action = models.TextField()
    UNIPROT_Link_Target_Molecule = models.URLField()
    EMBL_Link_Target_Molecule = models.URLField()
    Related_Citations = models.URLField(max_length=400)
    Annotator = models.EmailField()
```

quorum_sensing_text.txt

```
{{ object.text }}
{{ object.Inducer_Name_Synonym_Abbreviation }}
{{ object.Category_Inducer_Molecule }}
{{ object.Amino_Acid_Sequence_Inducer }}
{{ object.Organism_Involved }}
{{ object.Target_Protein }}
{{ object.Broad_Functional_Category_Target_Molecule }}
```

Comment: The first line in your template `{{ object.text }}` is wrong/not needed, try without that.

Comment: Thanks 21Zoo, I discovered the route cause to the problem was a corrupted field.py file. Not sure how it got corrupted but I traced the error to this file, replaced the file, and now the text field is populated.